# replace all specific character inside div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace all the commas (",") inside the div with a character. I've tried googling and it seems .replace() replaces only the first comma and it removes the links from the `text1`.

How do I replace all the commas with another character inside the div without it removing the links, using jquery?

```
<div> 
   <a href="#">text1</a>, <a href="#">text2</a>, <a href="#">text3</a>, <a href="#">text4</a>,
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all text node inside the div and update it, that will be the better way than updating entire html inside div.

```js
$('div')
  .contents() // get all child nodes
  .each(function() { // iterate over them
    if (this.nodeType == 3) // check node type is text
      this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/,/g, '+'); // update text content if it's text node
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">text1</a>, <a href="#">text2</a>, <a href="#">text3</a>,
</div>
```

Comment: Based on jQuery's documentation this would only work if the text nodes that need to be edited are direct descendants of the `<div>`. In this case it obviously works but is there an easy method for applying a search and replace for all descendant text nodes?

Comment: I'd rather not ask an entirely separate question just to get this clarification..

Comment: @PatrickRoberts : you can use recursion method for that..... if the nodeType is element then do the same again...

Comment: Why not the same thing, but using the selector `$('div *')`?

Comment: @PranavCBalan - ah yes, I meant why not the same thing, but use the selector `$('div, div *')`

Answer (score 3):

It will replace all , with 'a' character. use of the "g" within this - that stands for "global" and causes the replacing of all of the target characters in the string - without it you just replace the first instance as you have discovered.  try it.

```
string.replace(/\,/g, 'a');
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the `\,` comma? Has comma `,` a special meaning in RegExp?

Comment: $roko The \‍ is the begin of an escape sequence